# How can I get lists from DB flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flash-message

Is there a way to get a list from my DB?

I have this in my code:

```
graph_avg_session_duration = AnalyticsData.query.filter_by(name='graph_sessions').first()
item = graph_avg_session_duration.value
print(item)
```

The value in the DB is: `[0, 0, 50, 52]`

But when I check the type it says string but I need this to be type list.
I tried doing `list(item)` but this just makes a list item every char so doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know about your DB, but if you want to convert that string into a list and each element is a integer* you could try this, without using libraries:

`list( int(x) for x in item.replace('[', '').replace(']','').split(', '))`

*integer could be replaced with float etc